# My student is receiving an error message when the tbl_regression(), after installing a more recent package version #gtsummary

Tags: gtsummary

One of my students has been using the tbl_regression() function to create summary tables of his regression analysis.

However, he recently bought a new laptop and installed the latest versions of R and gtsummary etc, and now he says his code does not work. I am not very familiar with the gtsummary package, so I am unable to confidently explain why, but I can only assume this is due to an update.

I did find this, https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/news/index.html but since i do not use this package it is not 100% clear to me what the alternative solution is.

Here is a reproduceable example.

```
  mtcars %>% 
    tbl_regression(method = glm, y = am,
                     method.args = list(family=binomial), 
                     exponentiate = T, conf.int =  TRUE) %>%  
    bold_p() -> TableUnivPOD
```

Which gets the error "Error in ~am : object 'am' not found"

He claims this code worked fine before he installed the latest versions. The code should make a table summarizing the coefficients from his logistic regression model.

Thanks

Lewis

Comment: Your student was likely using `tbl_uvregression()` NOT `tbl_regression()`. If they update the function call, the code works